# how to get the length of the column size in two dimensional array by calling constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, constructor

trying to get the size of the column in 2d array to be able to run `addGrades` function by calling 2d array from the constructor. Technically, when the constructor calls the function, function needs to know the length of the column to be able to run the process and once the function executes, the user will input values from keyboard.

how to get the size of the column ?

```
public class Grades {

    private int numOfRows;
    private int numOfColumns;
    private int[][] arr;

    public Grades(int numOfRows, int numOfColumns) {
        this.numOfRows = numOfRows;
        this.numOfColumns = numOfColumns;
    }

    public Grades(int[][] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }


    public Grades addGrades(Grades o) {

        //int len = o.getArr().length;//gets the length of the array

        int x =
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < lengthCol) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                System.out.println("add grades for class 1");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < numOfColumns; j++) {
                        arr[i][j] = s.nextInt();
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                break;
            }// end of counter one if statement
```

Comment: The only thing you get by calling a constructor is a new object.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the way to get is the length of the second dimension array.

Since this array depends on the first dimension it can have different lengths depending on the first dimension position.

In this case you have an array of arrays so you have a fixed size for the array of arrays and a different length for each array inside.

For example:

```
arr[0].length; // can be 8 while
arr[1].length; // and might be 2
```

So for accessing the lenght of them you can use:

```
arr.length;    // legth of the array of arrays
arr[i].lenght; //length of array in position i
```

In your case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  int numOfColumns = arr[i].length;

  for (int j = 0; j < numOfColumns; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = s.nextInt();
  }
}
```